# ExportAsFixedFormat throws Exception when exporting to wdExportFormatXPS

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word, office365, office-interop

We were using the following lines of code for long time now (using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`):

```
ApplicationClass wordApp = new ApplicationClass();
Document wordDoc = null;
wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(file);
wordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat(filexps, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatXPS);
```

But since today the last line throws an `COMException`:

> Fehler beim Exportieren, weil dieses Feature nicht installiert ist.

which translated says (I wasn't able to find the exact translation)

> Error while Exporting. Feature missing

Did anything change regarding XPS export? Is there any other way to export to XPS?

Or is there any other way to view a DOCX-document in WPF? Because the only reason for exporting to XPS is the use of of `DocumentViewer` from `System.Windows.Controls`.

We are using Office 365 ProPlus 1902 (Build 11328.20468) and no, nothing was changed before... **really**... *I think*...

Comment: There may have been a Microsoft Update, either Windows or Office, that interfered with the tool...

Comment: was my first thought too, but it was just a software cleanup... see answer below

Answer (score 0):

(Re-)Installing `Microsoft XPS Document Writer` solved the problem...

You know, **nothing** was changed before...